# Another question on Mma data sources/syntax

Tags: curated-data, chemistry, natural-language

Let's say I want to have the vapor pressure of mercury, as a function of temperature. I know that this information is available, for any specific temperature, from Wolfram Alpha, and I can also get the information in Mathematica by using natural language recognition, and typing something like "vapor pressure of mercury at 100C", say.

However, is there a Mathematica function I can use to, say, plot the vapor pressure as a function of temperature? If so, how would I be able to discover it? `ElementData` and `ThermodynamicData` do not seem to have that information.

I see that, if I type something like "height of Eiffel tower", it gets converted to something that has input form `Entity["Building", "EiffelTower::5h9w8"][EntityProperty["Building", "Height"]]`, so in this example I can figure out what Mathematica function I could call to get the data I want.

However, if I ask for the above vapor pressure, all I get is a number with units. If I ask for just "vapor pressure of mercury", I do get `Entity["Chemical", "Mercury"][EntityProperty["Chemical", "VaporPressure"]]`, and I found that I can ask for `ChemicalData["Mercury", "VaporPressure"]`, but I'm not told under what conditions this vapor pressure holds (if I do `ChemicalData["Mercury", "VaporPressure", "Conditions"]` I get no information), and there seems to be no way to get the pressure for a specified temperature.

Comment: If push comes to shove, you can manually implement the equation detailed [here](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/506/NISTIR.6643.pdf). For serious work, I wouldn't use Alpha's values unless there was an explicit description of what formula (e.g. Antoine's) was being used, which it doesn't have.

Comment: WA uses many custom functions no present in the WL, and this is one of those cases, since "Mercury" is not an entity in `ThermodynamicData`.  I believe the source in this case is [here](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/kentlab/How_to/ChemicalInfo/VaporPressure/Pressure.pdf)